# Problema ao compilar math.h

Tags: c, c++, matemática, compilação, compiladores

Boa noite, quando eu tento usar alguma função de math.h e coloco como argumento uma variável e tento compilar eu recebo um erro. Sabe me explicar porque isso está ocorrendo?

Segue um código de exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    int cacheSize = 4;
    int memSize = 16;

    // log de cacheSize na base 2
    double cacheBits = 0;
   cacheBits = log(cacheSize)/log(2);

   // log de memSize na base 2
   double memBits = 0;
   memBits = log(memSize)/log(2);

   return 0;
}
```

A mensagem de erro que recebo:

```
gcc teste.c -o teste

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccHF5avR.o: na função "main":
teste.c:(.text+0x25): referência não definida para "log"
/usr/bin/ld: teste.c:(.text+0x51): referência não definida para "log"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se obtém esse erro é porque a implementação da biblioteca math não está a ser linkada no processo. Para resolver acrescente o `-lm` na instrução de compilação:

```
gcc teste.c -o teste -lm
```

Quando inclui o `math.h` inclui a definição das funções mas não as suas implementações, e por isso é que vê esse erro.